# In .NET 3.5 C#, is there a way to detect if NVIDIA SLI mode is active

Tags: c#, .net, nvidia, sli

For NVIDIA graphics cards, you can have two working as one (SLI). For a .NET desktop application, I need to be able to check that SLI is enabled. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be possible.

According to the nVidia docs, you can query this [via NVCPL.DLL](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/9.5/Samples/DEMOS/common/src/NvCpl/docs/NVControlPanel_API.pdf) (liked to documentation).

The call to be used is `NvCplGetDataInt()` (page 67), with the argument `NVCPL_API_NUMBER_OF_SLI_GPUS` or `NVCPL_API_SLI_MULTI_GPU_RENDERING_MODE` you should obtain the information required.

In oder to access this information, you'll need P/Invoke. If it is OK to statistically link `NVCPL.DLL` you just have to create the correct import (static external method) and you're fine. Otherwise, you can also choose the `LoadLibrary` and `GetEntryPoint` way and use the `Marshal` class to create an instance of a delegate (declared with the correct arguments) which represents the function to be called.

**Edit:**
The following snippet may get you started (I don't have a nVidia card though, so that's completely untested and on your own risk ;) ):

```
public const int NVCPL_API_NUMBER_OF_GPUS =7;    // Graphics card number of GPUs. 
public const int NVCPL_API_NUMBER_OF_SLI_GPUS = 8;    // Graphics card number of SLI GPU clusters available. 
public const int NVCPL_API_SLI_MULTI_GPU_RENDERING_MODE = 9;    // Get/Set SLI multi-GPU redering mode.  

[DllImport("NVCPL.DLL", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern bool nvCplGetDataInt([In] int lFlag, [Out] out int plInfo);

public static void Main()   {
    int sliGpuCount;
    if (nvCplGetDataInt(NVCPL_API_NUMBER_OF_SLI_GPUS, out sliGpuCount)) {
        // we got the result
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("SLI GPU present: {0}", sliGpuCount));
    } else {
        // something did go wrong
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to query NV data");
    }
}
```